# OpenCV writes video to massive (27Gb) file

Tags: python, opencv, video

I'm modifying a video using Opencv3.0 in python3.6, by occasionally adding a dot to a frame and then saving the file again. I save it using
`video = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, 24.0,  (720,576))` with
`fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')`, and then finally             `video.write(frame)`.

But while I started with a three-hour video of 10Gb I know end up with a 27 Gb file. Is there anyway I can tell OpenCV to compress the file?

Comment: Try integrating in H264 with the raw data to encode and compress it.

Comment: So far avi is the only file that doesn't give an error and it's definitely a smaller file, but the video is scrambled...

Comment: Is that giga**bits**, or actually giga**bytes**? The small `b` suggests the former, but the latter would make more sense. | 27 GB per 3 hours gives you about 2.5 MB per second, so unless it runs at 1FPS or is thumbnail sized, there's definitely compression happening, just not as aggressive as it was in the original.

Comment: haha yh definitly GB, i fixed the issue by running handbrake on the video, which had a video encoder which made it a lot better, thank you all!